# $I, A, B, A^2, B^2, AB + BA, AAB + ABA + BAA$ are linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, real-numbers

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Let $A$, $B$ be $3 \times 3$ matrices over real numbers. Then $I, A, B, A^2, B^2, AB + BA, AAB + ABA + BAA$ are linearly dependent.

I guess, one could just write in coordinate form expression $$ I \wedge A \wedge B \wedge A^2 \wedge B^2 \wedge (AB+BA) \wedge (AAB + ABA + BAA) $$
And then simplify it down to zero, but it will take a lot of calculations. Is there any simpler or shorter solution?

Comment: This is a well-known exercise (I will try to find it back here).